# specify callback on jquery bounce?

Tags: jquery

```
Data.BouncePrompt.effect("bounce", {times:3, mode:"hide"}, 300);
```

I want to let it continue displaying after the 3 bounces for like 2 seconds then hide it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing:

```
Data.BouncePrompt.effect("bounce", {times:3}, 300, function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6agah/

Comment: So does jQuery just let you throw a function in the last parameter in most of its functions, and that is always the callback? I was looking for a specific entry in the documentation, but seems like u can just whip it on most things?

Comment: any reason for having mode: hide aswell?

Comment: No--Things that happen asynchronously traditionally take a callback function. Check out the "arguments" tab in [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#option-callback) for effect. (And I just edited out the `mode` parameter, sorry about that `:)`)